# How to create a custom filter for searching full table with Tablesorter lib?

Tags: javascript, jquery, tablesorter

I would like to create an external custom filter based on full text search over all (or several) columns (also searching in child rows, with custom text extraction functions for all nodes). Is it possible using the [Tablesorter](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter).

Everything I found was an external custom filter, but only for a certain column, not for multiple columns

Comment: How would the customfilter work? I assume that a user enters his searchphrase into a searchbox and inside the table only the rows that contain the searchphrase are visible?

Comment: I think that datatables plugin may work for you.   Here is a fiddle to see it in action. [jsFiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/M2mUF/)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible... do the following:

- Set up a single custom search input for searching the table. Bind to it using this function: `$.tablesorter.filter.bindSearch( $table, $('.search') );`

  `$('.search')` being the input.
- Set the [`filter_anyMatch` option](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#widget-filter-anymatch) ([demo](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-widget-filter-any-match.html)) to `true` to allow using a single search input to match contents in multiple columns.
- Set the [`filter_childRows` option](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#widget-filter-childrows) to `true` to include child rows content.
- Then set the [`filter_useParsedData` option](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#widget-filter-useParsedData) to `true` to only search through the parsed data (obtained via the custom text extractions)

Please be aware that the `filter_anyMatch` option does put some limitations of the types of filter searches. It's all detailed in the demo link shared above.

Comment: Thank you very much Mottie for your personal answer here! The `filter_anyMatch` sounds the right option, but as long as all options are set centrally for the whole table isn't it will be so that all internal filters (per column) will have such a behaviour? How to differentiate between internal and external filters so?

Comment: hm, if I set `filter_anyMatch : true` the internal filters are stopping to work (nothing is filtered)

Comment: Hmm, you didn't mention that you'd be using both internal & external filters. Umm, I think I might need to modify the filter widget to differentiate internal vs external searches and/or allow dynamic toggling of the `filter_anyMatch` option. I might not be able to do anything until after the new year since I'm going out of town. I did [open an issue](https://github.com/Mottie/tablesorter/issues/471) to remind me to work on it. Please check there for updates.